# rails react webpack can't load images

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, reactjs, webpack

I used command as bellow to create a new application (use `react webpack`)

I used rails `5.1.4`

```
rails new news --database=postgresql --webpack=react
```

and i had some images was put in `app/assets/images`, so in folder `app/javascript/src/components/test.jsx`, i want to display this `images` which was put in `assets/images`.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import addBanner from 'images/addbanner_728x90_V1.jpg';

class Header extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <header id="header">
        <img src={addBanner} alt="" />
      </header>
    )
  }
}
```

and this is my `webpacker.yml`

```
default: &default
  source_path: app/javascript
  source_entry_path: packs
  public_output_path: packs
  cache_path: tmp/cache/webpacker

  # Additional paths webpack should lookup modules
  # ['app/assets', 'engine/foo/app/assets']
  resolved_paths: ['app/assets']
```

when i run `rails server`, the images didn't display on my website.

this is an error which displayed on `debug console` of `chrome`.

```
GET http://localhost:3000/packs/_/assets/images/addbanner_728x90_V1-b8833c72a88a27dde49f4c9067bef50d.jpg net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT
```

How can i display this image ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely because the name is `addbanner_...jpg`, its being blocked by adblock, because it thinks it is an advert. Try to disable adblock, or change the name of the image.